# Transferring from Outlook to Apple Mail (OLM to Mbox)

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, apple-mail, mbox

I recently had to transfer my emails from Outlook to Mail on OSX/Mac. All the articles I found online seem to be recommending utilities that cost money and I'd like to know if this can be done without spending money or using a utility.

So, how do I (or, can I) transfer my Outlook mail (OLM) to the Apple Mail program (Mbox)?

Comment: Thanks for your question Andre. I've removed the software request portion of your question as that is very much against the rules here on SuperUser. As you already figured out a good answer that does not require a utility, free or otherwise, this should help keep this good question here.

Comment: You should actually be able to mark your answer as The Answer now too.

Comment: Outlook offers an Export option in the File menu, but I'm not certain if it allows exporting emails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out you can simply drag and drop your mail folders to a folder in Finder. This will automatically create an Mbox file, as illustrated below.

[image]

You can now simply import the Mbox file in Apple Mac by going to `File > Import Mailboxes > Files in Mbox format > Continue > Select the Mbox file > Choose > Done`.

Your old inbox will now be available under the Import folder, as below:

[image]

Comment: There is another automated solution available for Outlook to Apple Mail conversion i.e [Mac OLM to MBOX converter](https://macwaretools.com/converter/olm.html).